Share database cursor across multiple threads with Celery
I have a single worker in celery that uses sqlalchemy and takes an input table (in one db) and a output table (in another db) and it retrieves and transfers the data from one to the other.
I'd like to parallelize this across celery workers so that each worker is dealing with x/n-of-workers rows.
I know I could probably refactor this to split up the start/end rows that each worker would deal with, but is there a way to have the celery workers share the proxy.fetchmany() calls until they're exhausted?
Here is some example code of it working in singular:
    logging.info("Connecting to Database")
    connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": self.SOURCE_CONNECT_STRING})
    source_eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)
    source_connection = source_eng.connect()

    # Select all rows
    query = f"SELECT * FROM {sourceTable} WITH (NOLOCK)"

    stmt = sqlalchemy.text(query)

    proxy = source_connection.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(stmt)
    
    column_names = list(proxy.keys())
    logging.info(column_names)

    insert_stmt = f"""INSERT INTO {destTable} ({','.join(column_names)}) VALUES ({','.join(['?']*len(column_names))});"""

    if ( hasIdentity ):
      insert_stmt = f"""
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT {destTable} ON;
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        {insert_stmt}
        SET NOCOUNT OFF;
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT {destTable} OFF"""

    completed = 0
    while 'batch not empty':  # equivalent of 'while True'
      batch = proxy.fetchmany(self.INITIAL_BATCH_SIZE)
      if not batch:
        break

      # Strip whitespace from batch
      batch = [self._strip_tuple(i) for i in batch]
      
      logging.info(f"Inserting {str(len(batch))} rows.")
      with pyodbc.connect(self.DEST_CONNECT_STRING) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
          cursor.fast_executemany = True
          # Send pyodbc call
          logging.info(insert_stmt)
          cursor.executemany(insert_stmt, list(batch))
          conn.commit()
          completed += len(batch)
      logging.info(f"Completed inserting {completed} rows into {destTable}.")

    proxy.close()


Each Celery worker would be its own separate process without knowledge of what the other processes are doing, so no, they can't share access to the proxy that is defined in one of the processes. If you want the processes to coooperate/share info, multiprocessing is probably what you're looking for.

If you want to use Celery, each task could have arguments that limit the rows that the worker accesses, like you suggested.
